# Returning multiple class types from a function

Tags: c++, class, templates

If I have a simple program as follows:-

```
class Program
{
    public:
       my_func(void)                 \\ What return type do I use here??
       {
            switch (i)               \\ assume i comes from somewhere...
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    Glue g;
                    g.init();
                    return g;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    Wood w;
                    w.init();
                    return w;
                }
                ....
            }
        }
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can set the return type of this function to be an object created in one of the switch cases?  Also because of time constraints, I can't use new/delete for creating the objects or I'd just return a void* ptr.  The objects created in the switch are sufficiently large, so is it possible to create them in each case and return a reference to them, without them going out of scope?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.  If you have two questions, create two SO questions.

Comment: The second problem, which belongs in another question, is returning a dangling non-const reference in `my_func_2()`. What do you think that reference refers *to* back on the caller side? Still grappling with what you're actually trying to do with the first question, which looks like trying to use a template to provide an overload (which, for what it seems you're trying to accomplish, isn't right either).

Comment: Search the web for "C++ factory Example".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, it's good design to define a base class from which the possible types of the objects returned derive. For example, let Glue and Wood derive from a class called `Carpenter` or `CarpenterObject`, you'll need in it an indicator of what the object is actually.

```
class Carpenter
{

public:

    static const int UNKNOWN = -1; //example only
    static const int GLUE = 0;
    static const int WOOD = 1;

    virtual int Type() { return UNKNOWN; }

    Carpenter* GetSomething();

};

class Glue: public Carpenter
{
    virtual int Type() { return Carpenter::GLUE; }
};

class Wood: public Carpenter
{
    virtual int Type() { return Carpenter::WOOD; }
};

Carpenter* Carpenter::GetSomething()
{
    Glue* g = new Glue();
    Wood* w = new Wood();

    return g; // or w
}

void main()
{
    Carpenter p;
    cout<<p.GetSomething()->Type();
}
```

I think the second question deals with a warning not an error (it works normally with me), but I'm using Visual Studio 2012's compiler.

Comment: Your very first sentence is the ideal answer (and something I already have, but my mind has obviously had a thrown an exception in the exception hanlder!)

The only issue I have with your answer is, I cannot use new to create the object, or it would be easy.  I have to create the object in each case statement (as each case creates a different object) and then return that object.  (or as you suggest, the base object)

Answer (score 3):

One solution to the first problem is the obvious: get a hierarchy and return a base type. An alternative solution is to use a Variant type, like [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html). Then you could define your return type as: `boost::variant<Wood, Glue>`. This is often the preferable approach when a hierarchy would be unnatural or would add complexity. On the other hand the hierarchy approach is simpler to execute and some people don't eschew the template magick that comes with Variant classes.

Please be aware that rolling your own Variant type can be a quite complex undertaking and prefer a library.

Your second question boils down to: get a better compiler. Both a recent version of clang and gcc 4.8 report warnings for both functions.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem can be solved by using the second questions approach. That is make `Glue` and `Wood` inherit from the same base class and pass reference to the function. This way you don't have to return a reference of a local variable and you can return the type you wanted.

```
struct Obj {

    virtual void init() { cout << "Obj"; }
};

struct Wood : public Obj {
    virtual void init() { cout << "Wood"; }
};


struct Glue : public Obj {
    virtual void init() { cout << "Glue"; }
};

struct Program {

    // Pass by reference the actual object. You want it created it here?
    // Why just create it outside. i.e move your case to the place where you know what i 
    // is. It doesn't have to be created here.
    void foo(Obj& o) { 
        o.init(); 
    }
};



int main()
{
    Program p;
    Obj* ref_p;

    // Move your case here.
    //case
        Wood w;
        ref_p = &w;
    // 
        //Glue g;
        //ref_p = &g;

    p.foo(*ref_p);
}
```

Comment: This is a gppd idea, but I did sort of simplify the code a bit for ease of typing etc.  In my actual program, the code has to be a single function that creates and returns that created object depending on which case is executed.  Each case creates a different object with different members etc, with a common init() function for each object.

Returning of a base class from which all objects derive is something I have actually already got, but my mind is obviously in cloud-cookoo land!  Moving the switch to somewhere where I know what object it is, isn't really an option.

Answer (score 0):

First program template concept applied incorrectly

as you have to pass the type replacing T when calling the function.

Second program i compiled in my compiler and it gives warning for both the functions

Comment: Sorry, deleted second part of the question because someone complained that I'd asked two questions in one!  Yes I know using a template to pass a type to a function, it was more about getting an unknown type from a function.